# ngCordova plugin for audio player

Tags: javascript, angular.js, plugin, audio, cordova

I wrote a Cordova plugin for an app that I'm working on, and now I'm trying to write an Angular definition to wrap my plugin.  So far, I've followed the model in [ng-cordova.js](http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/):

```
angular.module('ngCordova.plugins.audioPlugin', [])
.factory('$audioPlugin', ['$q', function($q) {

    return {
        init: function(sessionKey) {
            var q = $q.defer();

            AudioPlugin.init(sessionKey, function(response) {
                q.resolve(response);
            }, function (error) {
                q.reject(error);
            });
            return q.promise;
        },

        playAudio: function(contentId) {
            var q = $q.defer();

            AudioPlugin.playAudio(contentId, function(response) {
                q.resolve(response);
            }, function (error) {
                q.reject(error);
            });
            return q.promise;
        },

        seekChapter: function(contentId, partIndex, chapterIndex) {
            var q = $q.defer();

            AudioPlugin.seekChapter(contentId, partIndex, chapterIndex function(response) {
                q.resolve(response);
            }, function (error) {
                q.reject(error);
            });
            return q.promise;
        },

        getCurrentPosition: function() {
            var q = $q.defer();

            AudioPlugin.getCurrentPosition(function(response) {
                q.resolve(response);
            }, function (error) {
                q.reject(error);
            });
            return q.promise;
        },

        getCurrentChapter: function() {
            var q = $q.defer();

            AudioPlugin.getCurrentChapter(function(response) {
                q.resolve(response);
            }, function (error) {
                q.reject(error);
            });
            return q.promise;
        }

    }

}]);
```

I'm looking for feedback on how to structure this wrapper.  I'm a little unhappy with the amount of repetition involved to convert the callback-based architecture in the Cordova plugin to the angular promise-based style.

Answer (score 2):

## Bug:

You have a bug in the following line:

> ```
> AudioPlugin.seekChapter(contentId, partIndex, chapterIndex function(response) {
> ```

You're missing a comma after `chapterIndex`.

---

## Structure:

So, as `init` and `playAudio` follow the same style, as well as `getCurrentChapter` and `getCurrentPosition` following the same style, so you can substitute those out. Additionally, the `resolve` and `reject` functions can be taken out, leaving:

```
angular.module('ngCordova.plugins.audioPlugin', [])
.factory('$audioPlugin', ['$q', function($q) {
    function resolve(response){ return $q.defer.resolve(response).promise; }
    function error(error){ return $q.defer().reject(error).promise; }
    function generic(audioPluginMethod, parameter){
        if (parameter){
            return AudioPlugin[audioPluginMethod](parameter, resolve, error);
        }
        return AudioPlugin[audioPluginMethod](resolve, error);
    }
    return {
        init: generic('init', sessionKey),
        playAudio: generic('playAudio', contentId),
        getCurrentPosition: generic('getCurrentPosition'),
        getCurrentChapter: generic('getCurrentChapter'),
        seekChapter: function(contentId, partIndex, chapterIndex) {
            AudioPlugin.seekChapter(contentId, partIndex, chapterIndex, resolve, error);
        }
    }
}]);
```